# Validating DD-MM-YYYY formation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Below is my javascript first follow by my xhtml code am trying to get it to validate my date however it is picking up every date I entered as an invalid date, can someone please tell me what am missing  any help will do thanks in advance

```
function validateForm(form)
{
    var a, i, title, fname, lname, sex, address, email, username, password, confirm, error, check, type, contact, date;
    var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    var matches = /^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{4})$/.exec(date);

    a=0;
    check=false;
    error=false;

    //other codes
    date=document.getElementById('date').value;
    //other code

if (matches == null) 
    alert('Please enter a valid date of birth');
    return false;
    var d = matches[2];
    var m = matches[1] - 1;
    var y = matches[3];
    var composedDate = new Date(y, m, d);
    return composedDate.getDate() == d &&
            composedDate.getMonth() == m &&
            composedDate.getFullYear() == y;
```

below is my html

```
    <form name="myForm" method="post" action="sub.html" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <fieldset>

    <p>Last Name:<input id="lastname" type="text" name="lname" size="40" placeholder="Last Name"/>*</p>

    <p>Sex: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Male <input id="mletter" type="radio" name="sex" value="male"/> &nbsp; &nbsp; Female <input id="fletter" type="radio" name="sex" value="female"/>*</p>

    <p>Date Of Birth: <input id="date" type="text" name="dob" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY"/>*</p>

    <p>Address: &nbsp; &nbsp; <textarea id="address" rows="4"  cols="40" ></textarea>*</p>


    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the format before getting the value to `date`

Also, the `if` might need some braces to include `return false` with it

```
var matches, date;
//other codes
date=document.getElementById('date').value;
matches = /^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{4})$/.exec(date);
if(matches === null){
    alert('wrong date format');
    return false;
}
```

to check for an invalid date string format, first get the date string to be checked

```
date=document.getElementById('date').value;
```

then do an `exec` with `regexp`

```
matches = /^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{4})$/.exec(date);
```

dont do it in the reverse order.

Comment: but doing that I will not be able to check for invalid dates

Comment: In your code, at the time you are doing the `exec` the variable `date` is `undefined` or doesn't have any value. So everytime `matches` will be `null` whatever date you enter.

Comment: can I get an example please